# Defining ConnectionString in asp SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my database connectivity which I define under `<appSettings>` in `web.comfig`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConnStr" 
         value="Data Source=dsk-159\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"/>
</appSettings>
```

But the problem is that I am unable to access it from my aspx page as I am trying like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:goldsConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT distinct TechnologyId , [TechnologyName], [ChildId] FROM [TreeTable] where childid is null AND technologyid in(@hid1)">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hid1" Name="hid1" DefaultValue="23" />
     </SelectParameters>
```

In place of `<connectionStrings>` I want to define it in `<appSettings>`

Plesae tell the correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web.config should be like below:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ConnStr" value="Server=yourservername;Database=yourdatabasename;UID=yourusername;Password=youruserpassword"/>
</appSettings>
```

And your .aspx file should like following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ appSettings:ConnStr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM ticketmaster"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 5):

You know you can set the connection string in the code behind rather than inline, it's much cleaner.

```
SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnStr"];
```

Consider reading up on [ConfigurationManger.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the aspx part to this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT distinct TechnologyId , [TechnologyName], [ChildId] FROM [TreeTable] where childid is null AND technologyid in(@hid1)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hid1" Name="hid1" DefaultValue="23" />
</SelectParameters>
```

I have done 2 things:

1. removed the  tags.
2. changed the connection string name to match the name in the web.config
   (goldsConnectionString-->ConnStr)

Comment: Thanks for Reply.i done by code side. Actually i have defined my connection string in AppSetting in webconfig. so that was trying to acces from aspx page as i am unable to find from aspx so i done it on code behind like  SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnStr"];

Comment: I believe that my solution should work without the changes on the code side but if you can make changes on the code side (like @DGibbs answer) it's better solution. anyway, you should mark the answer that worked for you :-)

Comment: Hi David I tried the way u told  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT distinct TechnologyId , [TechnologyName], [ChildId] FROM [TreeTable] where childid is null AND technologyid in(@hid1)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hid1" Name="hid1" DefaultValue="23" />
</SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource> but i am getting error that   The connection name 'ConnStr' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Comment: your web.config contains the <b> tags?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the connection string in your code-behind page

```
SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString =
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSttings["ConnStr"];
```